# Блоки игнорируют элементы абсолютного позиционирования

Tags: html, css, position

Картинки с абсолютным позиционированием, как сделать, чтобы следующий блок разместился под картинками? Он размещается перед ними. 
[image: Как получилось]

[image: Как должно быть]

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Museo Sans Cyrl';
  src: url('../fonts/MuseoSansCyrl-100.eot'); /* IE9 Compat Modes */
  src: url('../fonts/MuseoSansCyrl-100.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), /* IE6-IE8 */
       url('../fonts/MuseoSansCyrl-100.woff2') format('woff2'), /* Super Modern Browsers */
       url('../fonts/MuseoSansCyrl-100.woff') format('woff'), /* Pretty Modern Browsers */
       url('../fonts/MuseoSansCyrl-100.ttf')  format('truetype'), /* Safari, Android, iOS */
       url('../fonts/MuseoSansCyrl-100.svg#svgFontName') format('svg'); /* Legacy iOS */
  font-weight: 100;
  font-style: 100;

}
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Museo Sans Cyrl';
  src: url('../fonts/MuseoSansCyrl-300.eot'); /* IE9 Compat Modes */
  src: url('../fonts/MuseoSansCyrl-300.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), /* IE6-IE8 */
       url('../fonts/MuseoSansCyrl-300.woff2') format('woff2'), /* Super Modern Browsers */
       url('../fonts/MuseoSansCyrl-300.woff') format('woff'), /* Pretty Modern Browsers */
       url('../fonts/MuseoSansCyrl-300.ttf')  format('truetype'), /* Safari, Android, iOS */
       url('../fonts/MuseoSansCyrl-300.svg#svgFontName') format('svg'); /* Legacy iOS */
  font-weight: 300;
  font-style: 300;
}
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Museo Sans Cyrl';
  src: url('../fonts/MuseoSansCyrl-500.eot'); /* IE9 Compat Modes */
  src: url('../fonts/MuseoSansCyrl-500.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), /* IE6-IE8 */
       url('../fonts/MuseoSansCyrl-500.woff2') format('woff2'), /* Super Modern Browsers */
       url('../fonts/MuseoSansCyrl-500.woff') format('woff'), /* Pretty Modern Browsers */
       url('../fonts/MuseoSansCyrl-500.ttf')  format('truetype'), /* Safari, Android, iOS */
       url('../fonts/MuseoSansCyrl-500.svg#svgFontName') format('svg'); /* Legacy iOS */
  font-weight: 500;
  font-style: 500;
}
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Museo Sans Cyrl';
  src: url('../fonts/MuseoSansCyrl-700.eot'); /* IE9 Compat Modes */
  src: url('../fonts/MuseoSansCyrl-700.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), /* IE6-IE8 */
       url('../fonts/MuseoSansCyrl-700.woff2') format('woff2'), /* Super Modern Browsers */
       url('../fonts/MuseoSansCyrl-700.woff') format('woff'), /* Pretty Modern Browsers */
       url('../fonts/MuseoSansCyrl-700.ttf')  format('truetype'), /* Safari, Android, iOS */
       url('../fonts/MuseoSansCyrl-700.svg#svgFontName') format('svg'); /* Legacy iOS */
  font-weight: 700;
  font-style: 700;
}
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Museo Sans Cyrl';
  src: url('../fonts/MuseoSansCyrl-900.eot'); /* IE9 Compat Modes */
  src: url('../fonts/MuseoSansCyrl-900.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), /* IE6-IE8 */
       url('../fonts/MuseoSansCyrl-900.woff2') format('woff2'), /* Super Modern Browsers */
       url('../fonts/MuseoSansCyrl-900.woff') format('woff'), /* Pretty Modern Browsers */
       url('../fonts/MuseoSansCyrl-900.ttf')  format('truetype'), /* Safari, Android, iOS */
       url('../fonts/MuseoSansCyrl-900.svg#svgFontName') format('svg'); /* Legacy iOS */
  font-weight: 900;
  font-style: 900;
}
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Museo Sans Cyrl';
  src: url('../fonts/MuseoSansCyrillic-100Italic.eot'); /* IE9 Compat Modes */
  src: url('../fonts/MuseoSansCyrillic-100Italic.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), /* IE6-IE8 */
       url('../fonts/MuseoSansCyrillic-100Italic.woff2') format('woff2'), /* Super Modern Browsers */
       url('../fonts/MuseoSansCyrillic-100Italic.woff') format('woff'), /* Pretty Modern Browsers */
       url('../fonts/MuseoSansCyrillic-100Italic.ttf')  format('truetype'), /* Safari, Android, iOS */
       url('../fonts/MuseoSansCyrillic-100Italic.svg#svgFontName') format('svg'); /* Legacy iOS */
  font-weight: 100;
  font-style: italic;
}
body {
 font-family: 'Museo Sans Cyrl', sans-serif;
 font-size: 17px;
}
                  /* Меню */
#header {
 background: url(../img/header.png) no-repeat center top;
 height: 747px;
}
.nav ul {
 margin-top: 32px;
 padding: 0px;
 margin-left: 30px;
}
.nav {
 padding-right: 0px;
}
.nav__main_menu_list {
 float: left;
 display: block;
 font-size: 11px;
 font-weight: 900;
 margin-right: 20px;
 letter-spacing: 0.2px;
}
.nav__main_menu_list a {
 text-decoration: none;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 color: #fff;
}
.nav__main_menu_list a:hover {
 background: #386075;
 border-radius: 3px;
 padding: 13px 12px;
 color: #fff;
}
.nav__main_menu_phone img {
 float: left;
 margin-top: 10px;
 padding-right: 15px;
}
.nav__main_menu_phone {
 font-size: 16px;
 font-weight: 900;
 color: #fff;
 margin-top: 15px;
}
.nav__main_menu_list:nth-child(5) {
 padding-right: 0;
}
      /* Конец Меню */

.heading h1 {
 font-size: 90px;
 font-weight: 900;
 color: #fff;
 text-align: center;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 letter-spacing: 27px;
 margin-top: 200px;
}
.heading span {
 font-size: 51px;
 letter-spacing: 8px;
}
.heading__img {
 text-align: center;
 margin-top: 110px;
}
.advantages h2 {
 font-size: 42px;
 font-weight: 900;
 text-align: center;
 margin-top: 77px;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 letter-spacing: 3px;
}
.advantages__list {
 background: #f4f4f4;
 text-align: center;
 font-size: 17px;
 font-weight: 100;
 height: 356px;
 width: 360px;
}
.advantages__list h3 {
 font-size: 20px;
 font-weight: 900;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 letter-spacing: 2px;
}
.advantages__img_left {
 background: url(../img/advantages_left.png) no-repeat center center;
 height: 80px;
 padding-top: 150px;
}
.advantages__img_top {
 background: url(../img/advantages_top.png) no-repeat center center;
 height: 80px;
 padding-top: 150px;
}
.advantages__img_right {
 background: url(../img/advantages_right.png) no-repeat center top;
 height: 80px;
 padding-top: 150px;
}
.advantages__line {
 background: url(../img/advantages_line.png) no-repeat center center;
 height: 1px;
 margin-top: 20px;
}
.advantages__list p {
 font-size: 17px;
 font-weight: 100;
 margin-top: 15px;
 line-height: 22px;
}
#first {
 background: url(../img/first.png) no-repeat center top;
 min-height: 790px;
}
.move h2 {
 font-size: 42px;
 font-weight: 900;
 color: #fff;
 text-align: center;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 letter-spacing: 5px;
 margin-top: 90px;
}
.move blockquote {
 font-size: 18px;
 font-weight: 100;
 font-style: italic;
 color: #fff;
 text-align: center;
}
.move p {
 font-size: 14px;
 font-weight: 900;
 color: #fff;
 text-align: center;
 letter-spacing: 4px;
 text-transform: uppercase;
}
.move_two {
 border: 1px dashed #fff;
 text-align: center;
 height: 160px;
 margin-top: 55px;
 position: relative;
}
.move_two_up img {
 position: absolute;
 left: 550px;
 top: -15px;
}
.move_two_down img {
 position: absolute;
 left: 550px;
 bottom: -15px;
} 
.move_two p {
 font-size: 19px;
 font-weight: 100;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 letter-spacing: 3px;
 color: #fff;
 margin-top: 45px;
}
.move_two h3 {
 font-size: 23px;
 font-weight: 900;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 letter-spacing: 3px;
 color: #fff;
}
.move_three h2 {
 font-size: 37px;
 font-weight: 900;
 color: #fff;
 text-align: center;
 margin-top: 50px;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 letter-spacing: 4px;
}
.move_three p {
 font-size: 18px;
 font-weight: 100;
 color: #fff;
 text-align: center;
}
.move_three a {
 font-size: 15px;
 font-weight: 900;
 color: #fff;
 text-align: center;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 border: 2px solid #fff;
 border-radius: 4px;
 padding: 24px 33px;
 text-decoration: none;
 text-align: center;
}
.move_three_button {
 text-align: center;
 margin-top: 50px;
}
.transport__service h2 {
 font-size: 42px;
 font-weight: 900;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 letter-spacing: 4px;
 text-align: center;
 margin-top: 100px;
}
.transport__service_img {
 position: relative;
}
.transport__service_img_left {
 position: absolute;
 left: 425px;
 top: 90px;
 z-index: 1;
}
.transport__service_img_right {
 position: absolute;
 right: 440px;
 top: 90px;
 z-index: 1;

}
.transport__service_img_top {
 position: absolute;
 left: 480px;
 z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Болгария ждет Вас!</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
 <header id="header">
  <nav>
   <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
     <div class="col-md-2 logo">
      <img src="img/logo.png" alt="logo">
     </div>
     <div class="col-md-7 nav">
      <ul class="nav__main_menu">
       <li class="nav__main_menu_list">
        <a href="#">Главная</a>
       </li>
       <li class="nav__main_menu_list">
        <a href="#">О компании</a>
       </li>
       <li class="nav__main_menu_list">
        <a href="#">ВНЖ и ПМЖ в Болгарии</a>
       </li>
       <li class="nav__main_menu_list">
        <a href="#">Недвижимость и переезд</a>
       </li>
       <li class="nav__main_menu_list">
        <a href="#">Контакты</a>
       </li>
      </ul>
     </div>
     <div class="col-md-3 nav__main_menu_phone">
      <img src="img/phone_icon.png" alt="icon">
      +7 (495) 12-321-345<br>
      +7 (495) 12-321-345
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </nav>
  <div class="container">
   <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12 heading">
     <h1>Болгария<br>
      <span>ждет Вас</span></h1>
      <div class="heading__img">
       <a href="#"><img src="img/heading.png" alt="d"></a>
      </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </header>
 <section>
  <div class="container">
   <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12 advantages">
     <h2>Наши преимущества</h2>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
   <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
     <div class="advantages__list">
      <div class="advantages__img_left">
       
      </div>
      <h3>Надежность</h3>
      <div class="advantages__line">
       
      </div>
      <p>
       Мы всегда придем к вам на помощь <br>в решении самых неоднозначных<br> вопросов
      </p>
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
     <div class="advantages__list">
      <div class="advantages__img_top">
       
      </div>
      <h3>Достоверность</h3>
      <div class="advantages__line">
       
      </div>
      <p>
       Достоверность - главный принцип<br> нашей работы. Мы знаем все тонкости переезда в Болгарию и оформления соответствующих документов
      </p>
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
     <div class="advantages__list">
      <div class="advantages__img_right">
       
      </div>
      <h3>Компетентность</h3>
      <div class="advantages__line">
       
      </div>
      <p>
       Наши специалисты с большим опытом работы помогут разобраться во всех юридических тонкостях переезда<br>
       на ПМЖ в Болгарию
      </p>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </section>
 <section id="first">
  <div class="container">
   <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
     <div class="move">
      <h2>Переезд в Болгарию</h2>
      <blockquote>«Если Вам не нравится то место, где вы находитесь -<br> 
      смените его, Вы же не дерево»</blockquote>
      <p>Джим Рон</p>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
   <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
     <div class="move_two">
      <div class="move_two_up">
       <a href="#"><img src="img/move_two.png" alt=""></a>
      </div>
      <p>Пришло время и перед Вами стоит вопрос</p>
      <h3>Как переехать в Болгарию на ВНЖ или ПМЖ?</h2>
      <div class="move_two_down">
       <a href="#"><img src="img/move_two.png" alt=""></a>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
     <div class="move_three">
      <h2>Мы знаем ответ</h2>
      <p>Подберем для Вас оптимальный вариант и предложим лучшие условия!
      </p>
      <div class="move_three_button">
       <a href="#">Узнать больше</a>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </section>
 <section id="four">
  <div class="container">
   <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
     <div class="transport__service">
      <h2>
       Недвижимость и транспортные услуги
      </h2>
      <div class="transport__service_img">
       <div class="transport__service_img_left">
        <img src="img/transport__service_img_left.png" alt="">
       </div>
       <div class="transport__service_img_top">
        <img src="img/transport__service_img_top.png" alt="">
       </div>
       <div class="transport__service_img_right">
        <img src="img/transport__service_img_right.png" alt="">
       </div>
      </div>
      <div class="transport__service_block">
       <div class="transport__service_block_up">
        <h3>Мечтаете о доме на солнечном берегу?</h3>
        <p>
         Или хотите выгодно инвестировать в  заграничную недвижимость? В любом случае - подходящий вариант уже ждет Вас! Большой выбор объектов жилой и коммерческой недвижимости и профессиональный сервис позволит провести сделку с удовольствием и получить нужный результат
        </p>
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </section>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Юзайте z-index;

Comment: как z-index может повлиять на ситуацию? Мне нужно чтобы блок просто разместился ниже. Чтобы не подгонять его марджинами, может есть более рациональный способ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Пример

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.block {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 1rem;
}

.block__title {
  font-size: 3rem;
}

.block__circles {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 25px 0 -35px;
}

.block__circle img {
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, .25);
}

.block__circle:nth-of-type(2) {
  margin: -35px -25px 0;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}

.block__inner {
  background: #f7f7f7;
  padding: 3rem 2rem;
  max-width: 600px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <div class="block">
    <h2 class="block__title">Title</h2>

    <div class="block__circles">
      <div class="block__circle">
        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100">
      </div>
      <div class="block__circle">
        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100/fffff/00000">
      </div>
      <div class="block__circle">
        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="block__inner">
      <h3>Title</h3>
      <p>Картинки с абсолютным позиционированием, как сделать, чтобы следующий блок разместился под картинками? Он размещается перед ними.</p>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```